# Moment.js unix timestamp is not matched with epoch timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I am using the unix() function of moment.js in node.js and it returns the timestamp and when i matched this timestamp with epoch timestamp (https://www.epochconverter.com/) then there is a difference of 18-20 sec.

moment().unix()

so anyone can help on this.

Comment: Maybe your local time is off by 18-20 seconds?

Comment: @flob no, there is 5:30 hr difference between my local and utc

Comment: Maybe there is 5:30:20 difference?

Comment: @flob my local time is 6:22 PM and UTC is 12:53:01 PM. so i have a gap of 5:30 hours between my local and utc time

Comment: 6:22 and how many seconds? The problem seems to be the number of seconds. Perhaps the local clock on your machine is wrong by a small amount, as flob suggested. momentJS can only get the unix value based on reading the system clock on the machine where it is executing.

Answer (score 1):

Please compare the result of `moment('2017-10-23 14:31:03').unix()` to the epoch converter for the **same** date and time; if they are equal, it means that your local machine (e.g., laptop) is not set to the right time.